# YAML mappings to objects

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

In dynamic languages like Python i know it possible to convert easily YAML mappings to objects. It can be be a very powerful feature and save a lot of coding.

I'm facing a problem when i try to map the `.yaml` file to an object.

**File:** `objtest.yaml`

```
---
  test: yaml test   
  option: this is option
...
```

**My Code:**

```
class MyTest(object):
    pass

testObj = MyTest()

f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'objtest.yaml'))

rawData = yaml.safe_load(f)

print rawData

testObj.__dict__ = yaml.load(f)

f.close()

print testObj
```

**STDOUT (with trace back):**

```
{'test': 'yaml test', 'option': 'this is option'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/CROW/ATE/Workspace/Sandbox/test.py", line 23, in <module>
    testObj.__dict__ = yaml.load(f)
TypeError: __dict__ must be set to a dictionary, not a 'NoneType'
```

**Question:**

As you can see the file is loaded to `rawData` but the class instance `testObj` has a problem when I try to load the `.yaml` file to it.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rawData = yaml.safe_load(f)` reads the file, and that means the later `yaml.load(f)` can't read any more data from the file. While you could rewind the seek pointer, there is absolutely no reason to: You've already loaded the YAML document (in a manner that is safer, too). Just do `testObj.__dict__ = rawData`.

That said, I have reservations about assigning to `__dict__`. It may or may not be implementation-defined, and in any case it reeks of a hack. There's zero validation, invalid data leads to a type error or attribute error (or with `YAML.load` instead of `safe_load`, even arbitrary other errors, including silent security breaches) later on in the program with no indication that the YAML file is at fault. A proper serialization library is a more robust and maintainable choice in the long run.

Comment: thanks! it solved the issue, about the `__dict__` I have a code that tests the YAML validity, do you still think that it's not safe? the YAML file is used as a config that must be **readable** to the user, that's why it was preferred over JSON and XML.

Comment: @KobiK I have nothing against YAML (I use it myself), I have something against fiddling with `__dict__` needlessly, for the aforementioned reasons. Validation (assuming it is correct) alleviates those concerns. Security issues have nothing to do with the `__dict__` assignment, that phrasing was misleading -- the exploit happens during the execution of `load`. But for user config, this is probably not a high priority concern anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do... Take a look at http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation about halfway down on the section on Constructors, Representers, Resolvers. If you really want your object to be able to be loaded, you want to create a SafeRepresenter and SafeConstructor for it.